# Variables dont update to new values between classes

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a basic RPG style game. I have made different classes for the various parts of the code, one for each of the main items involved (hero, door, monsters etc.)

For both the hero and door, i assign them random locations, shown below in the code, but for the door I run a while loop which makes sure that the door is a certain distance from the hero (using pythagorus).

However the while loop in the door class won't work as it always uses a value of 0 for both heroC and heroR (row and column of the hero). I am relatively new to using classes, but it doesnt seem to make sense as in HeroLocation I assign a random integer to these variables, and HeroLocation is called before DoorLocation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
class Hero(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Hero, self).__init__(10, 10, 1, 1, 0, 1)
        self.herolocations = list(range(1,6)) + list(range(10,14))
        self.heroC = 0
        self.heroR = 0
    def HeroLocation(self):
        #place hero
        self.heroC = random.choice(self.herolocations)
        self.heroR = random.choice(self.herolocations)

class Door:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hero = Hero()
        self.doorC = 0
        self.doorR = 0
    def DoorLocation(self):
        while ((self.hero.heroC-self.doorC)**2+(self.hero.heroR-self.doorR)**2) <= 128:
            self.doorC = random.randint(1, 13)
            self.doorR = random.randint(1, 13)

class game:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.hero = Hero()
        self.door = Door()
    def MakeMap(self):
        self.hero.HeroLocation()
        self.herol = self.Main_game.create_image(15+30*self.hero.heroC,15+30*self.hero.heroR, image = self.heroimage)        
        self.door.DoorLocation()
        self.doorl = self.Main_game.create_image(15+30*self.door.doorC,15+30*self.door.doorR, image = self.exitdoor)
```

NB there is a lot more code, but i have only posted what i felt was the relevant stuff, if you need more to crack the puzzle message me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the good `Hero` instance in `Door.DoorLocation`.

*Btw I really advice you to change class & methods name following [Pep 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id37).*

In `Door.__init__`, first line:

```
self.hero = Hero()
```

Here, you are instantiating a **new** `Hero`'s instance. But, in `game.MakeMap` you are calling `self.hero.HeroLocation()`.

This `self.hero` instance is not the same, because it was instantiated in `game.__init__` and not in `Door.__init__`.

I didn't try, but check what behaviour gives this update:

```
class game:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.door = Door()
        self.hero = self.door.hero
```

With this you now are calling the instance defined in `Door.__init__`, so when doing `self.hero.HeroLocation()` in `game` and `(self.hero.heroC-self.doorC [...]` in `Door` you are pointing the same instance.

Last thing, this solution may works, but is surely not what you really wants, I think a door should not store a hero, a hero should not store a door too, but here is more complex question about patterns.